# Ingress rewrite-target for inner url

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a ingress controller with 2 application, one is just a hello world and another with a real micro-service application. 
now when I curl my application(ingress seems working fine)
curl -v /test  -->it give hello-world 
curl -v /clus -->it redirects to my application (as application is a springboot with resources/static/index.html,it gets rendered when curl.
it curl -v /clus -->index.html -->expected but if I want to get curl -v /v1/heart-beat -->still it gives me index.html 
any idea why it is so ?
I think culprit is my ingress.yaml rewrite-target which always redirect to root? Any idea how to resolve it?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /

spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /clus
          backend:
            serviceName: clus-dev-svc
            servicePort: 80
        - path: /test
          backend:
            serviceName: hello-service
            servicePort: 80
```

Comment: In your ingress you defined path /clus. So, what you get if you do curl -v /clus/v1/heart-beat

Comment: @hoque: No i mean if the path is going in a nested way, cluster is the path and lets say your application has inner path like /cluster/in/v1/version . which means the same service need to invoke but with the different result set.

Comment: How was your Kubernetes cluster created? Is it cloud provisioned? Is it GKE, EKS, AKS? What is your Kubernetes version?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly is `/v1/heart-beat`?

Comment: The cluster is provisioned using kops in aws ec2 machine

Comment: @DawidKruk : it is just a ping with return 200

Answer (score 0):

Finally after a long search and R&D found the answer.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1


spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /clus/(.+)
          backend:
            serviceName: clus-service
            servicePort: 80
        - path: /test
          backend:
            serviceName: hello-service
            servicePort: 80
```

Initially thought to add regex but didn't worked, finally the above worked